# Атрибуты поиска или фильтра

Tags: php, mysql

В авито или в каких-то магазинах есть фильтры поиска или фильтры заказа товара.
например в Авито если выбрать Транспорт выводятся колонки с выбором модели транспорта, марки, сколько км и тд. А если выбрать одежду или обувь выводятся checkbox-ы.
В интернет магазинах же при заказе товара можно выбирать размер, цвет и тд. в зависимости от товара. как называется этот способ проектирования?

Comment: Фильтры, а как ещё... Вас интересует как это реализовать?

Comment: Просто кастомные фильтры ) создаешь их и вперед

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вас наверно интересует EAV Модель.
"Сущность-Атрибут-Значение" (EAV, entity-attribute-value model) — модель вертикальной базы данных и открытой схемы.
Это кратко, но если интересует более подробная информация, то можно почитать в [википедии](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model)

Comment: Красава) Спасибо